# Ansible : Using regular expression in the module "copy"

Tags: continuous-integration, ansible, ansible-1.x

## The context

I'm trying to build a `continuous-integration` platform and in a `Ansible` `playbook` I use the `maven-dependency-plugin:get` to download an artifact from a `Nexus` on the **master** which will be deployed on a remote server using the `Ansible` module [`copy`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html).

In order to make a lightweight and generic playbook, I defined a variable called `app_version` that, if it's defined, I download the given version and if not I download the *Latest* version from the `Nexus` repository. The artifact is downloaded in a given directory (`/tmp/delivery/`). Below my `Ansible` task:

```
- hosts: local
  tasks:
    - name: "Downloading the war"
      shell: >
           mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:get -DgroupId=App-DartifactId=App-Dversion={{ app_version if app_version is defined else 'LATEST' }} -Dpackaging=war -DrepositoryId=my-nexus -Ddest=/tmp/delivery/
```

## My problem

To assure the playbook genericity, I need to write a regular expression in the `Ansible` module [`copy`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) to pick the artifact having the pattern `app*.war` but it looks like the module don't provide this ability. Below my copy tastk:

```
- hosts: agir
  tasks:
    - name: "Copying the war"
      copy: src=/tmp/delivery/app*.war dest=/folder/app.war  owner=user group=group mode=0755
```

How can I use a regular expression in the module [`copy`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) ?

I'm using `Ansible 1.8`

Comment: note that isn't a regex, it's a glob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
  - name: "Copying the war"
      copy: src={{item}} dest=/folder/app.war  owner=user group=group mode=0755
      with_fileglob: /tmp/delivery/app*.war
```

But what if there are more than one file?
I would recommend to register `stdout` of previous `shell` command and get filename from there if possible.

Comment: Works fine ! Thank you. Concerning if there are more than one file, in my playbook, I remove the directory content before downloading the war.